# Connection String

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net application.there is a databinding section to a datagrid.But there have an error.I think it may be in web config-Connection string.
Connection String is like this

```
<add name="ArchitectConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.15,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Architect;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

the error is

Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

Please help me..

Comment: What type of authentication are you using? Windows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify a username/password to the end of the connection string,

```
";User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
```

Or if you are using Windows Auth then

```
"Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: Not if he is using Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string  is expecting a user id and password add the following string to the end of the connection string:

String to add:

Userid=myUserID;Password=!12345

Complete altered string example: